# Can I pipe colorized cat (ccat) in less?

Tags: colors, cat, less

I find out [`ccat`](https://github.com/jingweno/ccat) which is a command to colorize the usual `cat` command.
Is there a way to pipe this in `less` mantaining colors?

If I do `ccat config.json | less` there's no color!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `less -R` will show colorized output

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work with `less -R` as you can see with this asciinema: https://asciinema.org/a/Hw1n48N8VbJ0ak6mdrYkS5MvI

Comment: @Cirelli94 you also have to tell `ccat` to send colorised output *to* `less` (which it probably doesn't, like most decent tools when output is not a terminal). Probably with `--color=always` if it follows GNU conventions

Comment: Thanks for your help @muru, I find out the correct option in `ccat`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `cat --help` explain, I have to use `color` option:

```
-C, --color="auto": colorize the output; value can be "never", "always" or "auto"

Using color is auto both by default and with --color=auto.
With --color=auto, ccat emits color codes only when standard output is connected to a terminal.
```

So to have `less` colorized I need to do:

```
ccat --color="always" config.json | less
```